# randomforest explained variation

Tags: r, linear-regression, random-forest

I have the following dataframe. I would like to know which bacteria contribute more when comparing the location of the bacteria(categorical) and its pH(numeric).

For instance at the end i would like to say for example that a certain bacterial type is more frequently found in a certain location when looking at the temperature.

```
             Bacillus Lactobacillus Janibacter Brevibacterium Lawsonella     Location temperature
Sample1              2          30    164          8             21         48 bedroom    27
Sample2              0         211      0        996            195        108 bedroom   35
Sample3              1         938      1         21             38         43 pool   45
Sample4              0          95     17          1              4        334 pool   10
Sample5              0         192     91         25           1207       1659 soil    14
Sample6              0          12     33          6             12        119 soil   21
Sample7              0          16      3          0              0        805 soil    12
```

The idea is to run randomforest to select those features (bacteria) that are more important when looking at both the location and the temperature.

Is randomforest suitable for this ? When i run the follozinw command i get the following error:

```
randomForest(Location+Temperature ~.,data=mydf)
Error in Location + Temperature : non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

From the error it looks that i cannot use a continous and categorical variable together. How can i fix this ?

Is for exemple convert the numeric temperature variable to ranges of temperatures as a categorical variables would be a solution ?

In fact i have tried and it worked by converting the numeric temperature to ranges and pasting the location so that i have a combination of location and temperature.

```
randomForest(Location_temperature ~.,data=dat)
```

I get the list of important bacteria which is what i was looking for. Now how can i know which one contributes more to one location or another since my model i was using all sites ? For example how to check that your important variables(let´s say Bacillus is the most important from the randomforest model ) is important in the pool location (how much variation it explains in the pool) ??

Hope it is clear....

Comment: If you have questions about the interpretations of statistical models, you're more likely to get better answers at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic. This doesn't seem like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.